# API how to get tracked time grouped by user for each project

Tags: activecollab

I'm using ActiveCollab API v5 and I need to create request which returns me array of all projects with tracked time for each user who participated in this project.

I have tried many of this documentation (https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/), but any request has returned what i need.

Do you havy any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write an API to update every user visit of project. the api consist of user_id, project_id,event name and the time values will take from API side. this will create track history of specific project.

Second API will be read the table data which you had updated from API and send response of JSON array.